# jQuery each: If element is first-child else

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, each

So I'm trying to run an each loop in jQuery that has an if statement to determine if the element it's on is the first-child of it's parent and also have the else statement following (this seems to be the difficult part) to have other code run for those.

Everything I've tried and found only seems to work without the if and else..

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you post some code of what you are doing

Comment: "Any thoughts?" About what???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the following example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

there are a couple of ways to do it

```
$("table tr td:first-child").each(function() {
    //perform actions on all of the first TD elements
});
$("table tr td:not(:first-child)").each(function() {
    //perform actions on all of the other TD elements
});
```

Or

```
$("table tr td").each(function() {
    var td = $(this);
    if (td.is(":first-child")) {
        //perform actions on all of the first TD elements
    }
    else {
        //perform actions on all of the other TD elements
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It can't be that difficult ?

```
$('.elements').each(function(index, elem) {
     if ( $(elem).is(':first-child') ) {
         // it's a baby
     }else{
         // it's something else
     }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ujc6j/)